# When is a property created on the current object VS a prototype?

Tags: javascript, performance

I was reading Google's [JS optimization page](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-javascript), and got to this section:

> Place instance variable declaration/initialization on the prototype for instance variables with value type... This avoids unnecessarily running the initialization code each time the constructor is called.

I thought, "wait, then you can't change the values in your instance"

But turns out you can, and that surprised me.

Why, when you change a value provided to you by a prototype, does it get set on the object itself?

```
x = { one: 1 }
y = Object.create(x)
y.one // 1, of course
y.one++;
y.one // 2
x.one // 1! why isn't this 2?
```

**What is the rule that defines this behavior?**

Is it that a Left Hand Side lookup is always on the nearest object, but a Right Hand Side lookup will traverse the prototype chain?

If so, this would apply to both reference and value types, but perhaps the temptation to mutate (`y.arr.push(1)`) would be too much, hence Google's recommendation to do this only for values?

Comment: `Object.create()` creates a new Object. `Constructor.protoype` is so all new instances of the `Constructor`, as in when `new` is called, inherit the properties.

Comment: There is no "value type". Values have a type per [*ECMAScript Language Types*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-language-types). Perhaps [*primitive value*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-primitive-value) was intended.

Comment: @RobG: You know what they meant: primitive types, non-object types, types whose instances can't have properties. The types like number, null, etc where `a.foo = "bar"; a.foo` returns `undefined` or errors out. And indeed, OP, the intention is precisely to avoid reference-sharing the initialisation (whereas it does not matter with primitive types).

Comment: If you simply want the same exact Object just assign it to a `var` since it's not primitive.

Comment: @Amadan—yes, and [*the document*](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-javascript) goes on to explain that. However, simply using *primitive value*, which is an expression defined in the language specification, obviates the need to explain ambiguous jargon. ;-)

Comment: Granted. But the OP didn't use the non-standard term, Google's engineers did; so it is a bit misplaced to correct the OP, when their question is clearly understandable. If that was not your intention, and was only clarifying what the document was talking about, then I apologise for the unnecessary comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the property assignment (the [[[Set]]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-set-p-v-receiver) internal method) reaches the property on the prototypical object `x`, but the receiver is still `y`. Then, the property is defined on `y`. The property on `x` remains unaltered.

More technically, the assignment `y.one = 2` does this:

1. `y.[[Set]]("one", 2, y)` is called.
2. Since `y` has no `"one"` own property, the call is redirected to the parent `y.[[GetPrototypeOf]]()`, which is `x`.
3. `x.[[Set]]("one", 2, y)` is called.
4. Since `x` has a `"one"` own property which is a data property (i.e. not a getter/setter accessor) and is writable, a new property is defined on `y`
5. `y.[[DefineOwnProperty]]("one", PropertyDescriptor{[[Value]]: 2})`

If you don't want that, you can use custom accessors:

```js
var one = 1;
var x = {
  get one() {
    return one;
  },
  set one(value) {
    one = value;
  }
};
var y = Object.create(x);
console.log(y.one); // 1
y.one++;
console.log(y.one); // 2
console.log(x.one); // 2
```

Comment: That's still a `new` instance. You're just using shorthand of `Object.defineProperty()` to set a higher scoped variable.

Comment: @PHPglue Not sure I comprehend your comment. Using an object initializer is like adding properties to a `new Object()`, yes, if that's what you mean.

Comment: This is kickin'. Great step-by-step that applies my example to the spec, making both really understandable to me. Thanks Oriol.

Answer (score 3):

It is a bit more complex.

Right hand side: look up the prototype chain, find the first one that matches (whether getter or data property), or return `undefined` if none is found

Left hand side: look up the prototype chain, if you find a setter use that; otherwise, set a data value on the object itself.

It would be horrible if simple assignment changed a prototype. (Imagine, for example, the [International Prototype Kilogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilogram#International_prototype_kilogram) automagically changing weight if you chip one of your own kilogram weights, and the chaos that would ensue.)

> Does this mean an explicit setter only, not just any ol' editable property? Could I trouble you to ask for an example that has a setter higher up the prototype and an example that does not?

```js
var x = {
  data: 1,
  hidden: 1,
  set accessor(val) {
    this.hidden = val;
  },
  get accessor() {
    return this.hidden;
  }
};

var y = Object.create(x);

console.log("orig: x.data:", x.data, "; y.data:", y.data); // 1, 1

y.data = y.data + 1;
console.log("inc: x.data:", x.data, "; y.data:", y.data); // 1, 2

delete y.data; // removes y.data, so y.data is again looked up at x.data
console.log("del data: x.data:", x.data, "; y.data:", y.data); // 1, 1

console.log("----------");

console.log("orig: x.accessor:", x.accessor, "; y.accessor:", y.accessor); // 1, 1

y.accessor = y.accessor + 1;
console.log("inc: x.accessor:", x.accessor, "; y.accessor:", y.accessor); // 1, 2
console.log("     x.hidden:", x.accessor, "; y.hidden:", y.hidden); // 1, 2

delete y.accessor; // silent fail, y.accessor doesn't exist
console.log("del acc: x.accessor:", x.accessor, "; y.accessor:", y.accessor); // 1, 2
console.log("         x.hidden:", x.hidden, "; y.hidden:", y.hidden); // 1, 2

delete y.hidden;
console.log("del hidden: x.accessor:", x.accessor, "; y.accessor:", y.accessor); // 1, 1
console.log("            x.hidden:", x.hidden, "; y.hidden:", y.hidden); // 1, 1
```

The difference you can see demonstrated here is that we can delete `y.data` (data property) after `y.data = ...`, but we cannot delete `y.accessor` after `y.accessor = ...`, since it doesn't exist -- `x.accessor` was used to set `y.hidden`.

Comment: I'm trying to parse "LHS: look up the prototype chain, if you find a setter use that". Does this mean an explicit setter only, not just any ol' editable property? Could I trouble you to ask for an example that has a setter higher up the prototype and an example that does not?